# how to check is there a value in the other column of table?

Tags: php, laravel-9

In a laravel blade in third line of this code I want to check if parent_id exists in id column or not
please help me!
I'm using laravel 9

```
@if ($category->parent_id == 0)
no parent
@if ($category->parent_id)
no parent
@else
{{ $category->parent->name }}
@endif
```

I corrected it this way:

```
  @elseif (empty($category->parent))
```

Comment: Do you have any **question** about the given code? It does not look like valid PHP code after all, more like a Blade template

Comment: yes, it's a blade template, but i'm using directive php codes in blade

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the post. I want to check if parent_id exists in id column or not
@NicoHaase

Comment: thank you dear Nico, I corrected it this way:  @elseif (empty($category->parent))

Answer (score 0):

Balde:

you can use the `empty()` to check if empty.

```
@if ($category->parent == 0)
no parent
@elseif (empty($category->parent))
<p>no parent</p>
@else
{{ $category->parent->name }}
@endif
```

or `??` operator

```
{{ $category->parent_id ?? 'no parent' }}
```

You can use the `is empty` in twig as below:

```
{% if category is empty %}
  <p> No parent </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The original code doesn't look like twig syntax

Comment: he mentioned it in the comment. That he is using twigs.

Comment: I have edited the post. I want to check if parent_id exists in id column or not
i'm using blade in laravel

Comment: yes! it works! but need a correction and -id must be removed:  @elseif (empty($category->parent))

Answer (score 0):

Using exists() function for parent()

**Not that exists function works just with single relations (belongsTo, hasOne)**

```
// This will run SQL query // returns boolean 
$category->parent()->exists(); // Don't forget parentheses for parent()
```

If you want to save performance and not calling sql query

```
count($category->parent); // returns 0 if not exist
```

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work!
I have this relationship in my model:

 public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

Comment: thank you dear Ahmed, I corrected it this way:  @elseif (empty($category->parent))

Answer (score -1):

You can try by using isset() function

```
@if ($category->parent_id == 0)
no parent
@if (!isset($category->parent_id))
no parent
@else
{{ $category->parent->name }}
@endif
```

Comment: it does not work because parent_id always exist but It may not exist in the id column

Comment: I have edited the post. I want to check if parent_id exists in id column or not